# OpenStack Block Storage cannot create LVM physical volume

Tags: storage, openstack, lvm, cinder

I am trying to implement an OpenStack environment and following the Stein installation guide.
For the installation process, I am using multiple nodes running on Ubuntu (not in Virtual Box).

Right now, I would like to install Cinder Block Storage and already implemented the controller node successfully. However, I am struggling with Step 2 on the storage node *"Create the LVM physical volume /dev/sdb:"* and cannot fix it.

Error Message: *"Device /dev/sdb excluded by a filter"*

Same error for /dev/sda or /dev/sda1, ...

[Link installation guide](https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/stein/install/cinder-storage-install-ubuntu.html)

[error pvcreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdvoG.png)

[error pvcreate 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lAh6.png)

Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Comment: What does `pvcreate /dev/sdb -vvv` say?

Comment: As far as I can tell from `lsblk`: `sdb` is a `30GiB` disk and there is a `30GiB` partition on it => there is no space left on `sdb`.

Comment: Try `pvcreate /dev/sdb1` (you might have to `unmount` `/dev/sdb1` first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both disks (`/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`) are in use (mounted) in to the OS. So you can't use them and create PVs on them. Moreover one partition from `/dev/sda` is used to create another VG (`/dev/sda2` as PV).

If you do not use `/dev/sdb1` unmount it and use it for PV creation

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

I followed your approach and unmounted /dev/sdb1. Afterwards, cinder installation was successful!

Comment: @PFWS19, if you are happy with my answer feel free to upvote and/or accept  :)